# Can I restore a time machine backup from one partition to another on the same HD?

Tags: time-machine, partition, restore

My partitions are reversed so the one I use is the last out of two so I can’t enlarge it.

Comment: Do you mean restore your data out of a TM volume, and then delete the TM volume? Or do you mean move the TM data to another volume, which will then be the TM volume? Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore any TM backup volume onto any other Mac volume.

However: a valid backup is a **second** copy on a **separate physical device**.

I would not attempt restoring one partition to another without a separate copy of the files somewhere else, in case something goes wrong.

It's possible to accidentally confuse source and destination volumes; or the entire disk could fail during the transfer; or the partition map might get corrupted.

You would also need to satisfy yourself that all your files have been restored without error or omission, before deleting the old TM volume.

If a problem occurs on this disk, what will happen to your files?

Comment: Note that you cannot restore time machine backups across different computers. You have to use Migration Assistant